# does python have a partition_by function?

Tags: python

is there some established recipe for partitioning a list according to some predicate? What I want to do is like an itertools groupby, but the predicate is going to be some arbitrarily complicated function (and not just a key). For example, imagine a list of students, and each student has a list of courses, and I want to group by those with courses in common. So it would be something like:

```
def coursework_intersection(a,b):
     return set(a['courses']).intersection(b['courses'])

list_of_lists = partition_by(coursework_intersection, students)
```

Comment: I don't think this function is written into Python on its own, but it shouldn't be too hard to make either... Assuming you make `student` a class.

Comment: Your question doesn't makes sense to me. A predicate is a function returning a boolean. So your function isn't a predicate ! Can you give an example with input/expected output ?

Comment: it returns truth-y or false-y depending on if there is set intersection or not. an empty set is false-y.

Comment: `coursework_intersection` doesn't define an equivalence relation. If Alice shares a course with Bob, and Bob shares a course with Charlie, but Alice and Charlie have no courses in common, how should the partition go?

Comment: I think hes looking for something like `{student_name:[list,of,students,who,share,classes,with,student_name],...}`

Comment: @JoranBeasley: ah, well, he can have that as long as he doesn't call it anything with `partition` in the name ;-)

Comment: not disagreeing  :P ...

Comment: Entities, relations, partitions... Isn't all that graphs? NetworkX?

Comment: If either answer helped you, you should select one as a solution.

Comment: what I ultimately realized when reading the comments/answers, is that my question was poorly worded(!). But on the plus side the answers did give me better insight into what I actually needed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want what Joran says in comments then it's inherently an Omega(n^2) worst case running time because that's the size of the output in the worst case (where `coursework_intersection` always returns true). So let's just bite the bullet:

```
def associated_with(func, seq):
    for item in seq:
        yield item, (other for other in seq if func(item, other))
```

Note that the input is a sequence, not an iterable, since this is a multi-pass algorithm.

That could be optimized to call `func` half as many times, if we're allowed to assume that it's a symmetric function, although the cost is more memory use. It could also be optimized a bit into a one-liner `return ( (item, (other for other in seq if func(item, other))) for item in seq)`, but I judge that not the most readable way to introduce the code ;-)

Answer (score 1):

```
from collections import defaultdict

def group_by_classes(students):
    result = defaultdict(list)
    for student in students:
        result[set(student["courses"])].append(student)
    return result
```

which will result in a list of students for each unique set of classes (ie every occupied vertex of the class hypercube).